# Bash: list all the directories for which only contains two subfolders: folder1 and folder2?

Tags: bash

As in the title, can someone help to answer this only using the Bash?

I spent some time can't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Question isn't clear; could you rephrase that?

Comment: Are the sub-folders called exactly that or are you looking for directories that contain exactly 2 sub-folders?  Are any files allowed in the directory?  Are tools such as grep, sed, awk, python allowed which are regularly used with bash scripts. __Is this homework__?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, list the folders which only contains two folders, they are folder1 an folder2. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should list the directories containing only two folders `folder1` and `folder2`.

```
for i in $(find . -type d); do count=$(find $i -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l); [ $count -eq 2 ] && [ -d $i/folder1 ] && [ -d $i/folder2 ] && echo $i ; done
```

The above wouldn't care if the folders have other *files*.  If you want to ensure only directories `folder1` and `folder2`, say:

```
for i in $(find . -type d); do count=$(find $i -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | wc -l); [ $count -eq 2 ] && [ -d $i/folder1 ] && [ -d $i/folder2 ] && echo $i ; done
```

[Be warned that the above might not work with spaces in directory names.]

Answer (score 1):

This would list those directories without being redundant on searches.

```
#!/bin/bash

function check {
    local DIR SUBFOLDERS=()
    for DIR; do
        readarray -t SUBFOLDERS < <(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d)
        if [[ ${#SUBFOLDERS[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
            [[ ${#SUBFOLDERS[@]} -eq 2 ]] && echo "$DIR"
            check "${SUBFOLDERS[@]}"
        fi
    done
}

check "$@"
```

Run the script with

```
bash script.sh dir_to_search [optionally_another_dir_to_search ...]
```

Examples:

```
bash script.sh .
bash script.sh "$HOME"
bash script.sh /var /usr
```